# Replacing non-alphanumeric characters to html in crystal reports

Tags: html, crystal-reports, ascii

I'm building a crystal report that ouputs XML-formatted text for a third party application.

The 3rd party app can't handle non-alphanumeric characters, so I have to convert them to HTML to be processed. At present, I use this code to catch the most common characters:

```
stringvar output := {table.fieldName};
output := Trim(output);  
output := Replace (output,chrW(38),"&#38;");
output := Replace (output,chrW(59),"&#59;");
output := Replace (output,"!","&#33;");
output := Replace (output,chr(34),"&#34;");
output := Replace (output,chrW(35),"&#35;");
output := Replace (output,"$","&#36;");
output := Replace (output,"%","&#37;");
output := Replace (output, chrW(39),"&#39;");
output := Replace (output,"(","&#40;");
output := Replace (output,")","&#41;");
output := Replace (output,"*","&#42;");
output := Replace (output,"+","&#43;");
output := Replace (output,",","&#44;");
output := Replace (output,"-","&#45;");
output := Replace (output,".","&#46;");
output := Replace (output,"/","&#47;");
output := Replace (output,":","&#58;");
output := Replace (output,"<","&#60;");
output := Replace (output,"=","&#61;");
output := Replace (output,">","&#62;");
output := Replace (output,"?","&#63;");
output := Replace (output,"@","&#64;");
output := Replace (output,"[","&#91;");
output := Replace (output,"\","&#92;");
output := Replace (output,"]","&#93;");
output := Replace (output,"^","&#94;");
output := Replace (output,"_","&#95;");
output := Replace (output,"`","&#96;");
output := Replace (output,"{","&#123;");
output := Replace (output,"|","&#124;");
output := Replace (output,"}","&#125;");
output := Replace (output,"~","&#126;");
output := Replace (output, chrW(145),"&#145;");
output := Replace (output, chrW(146),"&#146;");
output := Replace (output, chrW(147),"&#147;");
output := Replace (output, chrW(148),"&#148;");
output := Replace (output, chrW(8212),"&#8212;");
output := Replace (output, chrW(8217),"&#8217;");
output := Replace (output, chrW(8220),"&#8220;");
output := Replace (output, chrW(8221),"&#8221;");
output := Replace (output,"£","&#156;");
```

It's unweildly and needs maintenance. I'm adding characters to this as I find them, but I'm left wondering if there's a way, possibly using AscW and ChrW, to dynamically identify and convert non-alphanumeric character to it's html/ascii equivalent within the string.

Answer (score 1):

I appear to have found this solution by adapting code designed to remove non-alphanumeric characters:

```
stringvar input := {table.fieldName};
stringvar output := '';
numbervar i;

input := Trim(input);

for i := 1 to Length(input) Step 1 do

  // 0-9 is 48-57
  // A-Z is 65-90
  // a-z is 97-122

  if not(input[i] in [chr(32), Chr(48),Chr(49),Chr(50),Chr(51),Chr(52),Chr(53),Chr(54),Chr(55),Chr(56),Chr(57),Chr(65),Chr(66),Chr(67),Chr(68),Chr(69),Chr(70),Chr(71),Chr(72),Chr(73),Chr(74),Chr(75),Chr(76),Chr(77),Chr(78),Chr(79),Chr(80),Chr(81),Chr(82),Chr(83),Chr(84),Chr(85),Chr(86),Chr(87),Chr(88),Chr(89),Chr(90),Chr(97),Chr(98),Chr(99),Chr(100),Chr(101),Chr(102),Chr(103),Chr(104),Chr(105),Chr(106),Chr(107),Chr(108),Chr(109),Chr(110),Chr(111),Chr(112),Chr(113),Chr(114),Chr(115),Chr(116),Chr(117),Chr(118),Chr(119),Chr(120),Chr(121),Chr(122)]) 
  then 

(output := output + "&#"+ cstr(ascw(input[i]),0)+";";)

else

  if (input[i] in [chr(32), Chr(48),Chr(49),Chr(50),Chr(51),Chr(52),Chr(53),Chr(54),Chr(55),Chr(56),Chr(57),Chr(65),Chr(66),Chr(67),Chr(68),Chr(69),Chr(70),Chr(71),Chr(72),Chr(73),Chr(74),Chr(75),Chr(76),Chr(77),Chr(78),Chr(79),Chr(80),Chr(81),Chr(82),Chr(83),Chr(84),Chr(85),Chr(86),Chr(87),Chr(88),Chr(89),Chr(90),Chr(97),Chr(98),Chr(99),Chr(100),Chr(101),Chr(102),Chr(103),Chr(104),Chr(105),Chr(106),Chr(107),Chr(108),Chr(109),Chr(110),Chr(111),Chr(112),Chr(113),Chr(114),Chr(115),Chr(116),Chr(117),Chr(118),Chr(119),Chr(120),Chr(121),Chr(122)]) 
  then 

(output := output + input[i];) ;

output
```

Not perfect, but it works. Does anyone have a better solution?